# How to perform model selection with LibSVM using Java Library?

Tags: java, machine-learning, libsvm

In search of an algorithm for tweets classification problem, i crossed with SVM. Starting with `LibSVM` i implemented a system using its java library(not command line) which is resulting around 50%-60% with linear function. Now i wish to perform Model selection, scaling, cross-validation and feature selection in a hope to improve my accuracy. Problem is, i couldn't find these features in Java Library by `LibSVM`. So what options do i have. considering i am a java programmer? And if the option is to write them myself, how, and with what algo? Should i go with any other machine learning library or algo for the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model selection process in SVM which helps you to select the best model, based on different parameters of function. In LibSVM library, model selection is done with the use of cross validation method. What it does is partitions your training data in several subsets and trains the model with different parameters every time with every data in order to improve the accuracy. this also eliminates the [over fitting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by model selection or scaling. I know LibSVM does cross validation but I do n't know about feature selection. I recommend to use R instead of java. There are many packages for different feature selection methods and also SVM like:

> e1071

Comment: Thank you VTT, the cross validation is actually the model selection. And i will consider R but i wonder if we can use it in actual production level projects with continuous flowing data.

Answer (score 0):

[JSAT](https://code.google.com/p/java-statistical-analysis-tool/) has an SVM implementation (not the exact same algorithm used by LibSVM, but solves the same problem) as well as many other algorithms, GridSearch, and feature selection methods.

bias note: I'm the author of the library.

Comment: Thank you Sir i will go through the JSAT and if i find it suitable i'll let you know. May be you can give me some advice on writing my own ABC or genetic algo based model selection project.

Comment: Genetic algorithms are mostly only useful when we don't have a good way to search the space otherwise. For parameter running Grid Search is fine, and Random search works well fi you have too many parameters.